# Using pandas.DataFrame.plot: sort legend by value

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am using the following code to create a pie chart of my pandas data frame, df.

```
data = df.groupby(["Weather Condition"])['Hours per Year'].sum()
ax = data.plot(kind='pie', labels=None, legend=True)
ax.get_legend().set_bbox_to_anchor((1.1, 1))
```

I get the following pie chart:

[image: Pie chart image]

However, I want the legend to be sorted out from the highest values to the lowest values instead of alphabetically. Does anyone know how to go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Sort the values in the DataFrame before plotting: `data=data.sort_values("Hours per Year")`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and what I did is the following:

```
# first sort the values of the dataframe column you're interested
data_sorted = data.sort_values(['Hours per Year'])
```

Then you plot it:

```
# ... 
data_sorted.plot(kind='pie', y='Hours per Year', legend = True)
```

Then your legend should be sorted as you want it as well.